# gerrit query - get latest commit hash for repo

Tags: gerrit

I am using automation to pull always ref/master from the project
Is there an option to query gerrit to have information about last merged commit (getting only HASG also acceptable) ?

Using git log is not an option

Comment: Not 100% sure what information you're after about the last merged commit.
You could use the SSH commands as shown here: https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/cmd-query.html

Happy to formulate a more structured response once I know what kinf of information you're after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I found is to query gerrit, the query is :

```
[gerritURL]/a/projects/[gerritProject]/branches/[gerritBranch]
```

Using python:

```
query =[gerritURL]/a/projects/[gerritProject]/branches/[gerritBranch]
changes = rest.get(query)
```